# Force "update (manual)" in the Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

Some application updates in Android Market are marked with red label "Update (manual)" instead of just orange label "Update". How I can publish my app update in the market as it will be visible as "Update (manual)"? I assume I need add some lines to manifest file, but I can mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I think if the update requires additional permissions than the existing version of the app, it will require manual update.